# IE caching problem

Tags: internet-explorer, http

In IE (8 at least, probably the rest too):

I make a request:

```
GET http://www.mydomain.com/ HTTP/1.1
```

the server responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
Last-Modified: Fri, 25 Mar 2011 10:52:34 GMT
Date: Fri, 25 Mar 2011 10:54:15 GMT
```

I make another request:

```
GET http://www.mydomain.com/ HTTP/1.1
If-Modified-Since: Fri, 25 Mar 2011 10:52:34 GMT
```

the server responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
Last-Modified: Fri, 25 Mar 2011 10:52:34 GMT
```

I then goto some page, say:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/somepage
```

which has a link on it:

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/">click me</a>
```

When I click this, IE displays the previously cached response for this the anchored URI, without even making a request.

Why is it not obeying `must-revalidate`? This works as I'd expect in FireFox and Webkit

How do I make it obey it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you haven't set a `max-age` or `Expires` in the response.

[`Cache-Control: must-revalidate`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4) tells clients that once this resource expires, they must revalidate it against the origin:

> the cache MUST do an end-to-end revalidation every time, if, based solely on the origin server's Expires or max-age value, the cached response is stale

---

Since you don't declare when the page becomes stale, IE8 relies on [heuristics](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2.2) to make an educated guess. If you want IE to revalidate the page **every** time, you need to add appropriate headers to keep the expiry short:

```
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=1
Expires: [immediately, or even a date in the past]
```